# College/university time table generator

Tags: windows, planning, reservation

At our college, the total number of faculty members is almost close to 80 and six graduate courses are being run, every course has 8 semesters. In every semester, teachers have to teach a huge number of subjects every week. There is another big problem, that we have only 42 rooms having student seating capacity ranging from 40 to 90 students and student strength in every class is also variably ranging between 35 to 80 students. There are six labs too.

For manually generating a timetable for our college we are constrained by following restrictions:

1. Every teacher takes 16 lectures every week each of one-hour duration.
2. There should be no clash of subjects.
3. There should be no inter-departmental clash when a single teacher takes classes in more than one department.
4. There should be no consecutive classes for a teacher, i.e. there should be a gap of at least one hour between his/her lectures.
5. As there is no attendance for teachers in our college, so every day there should be a gap of at least 4 hours between first and last lecture of teacher during single day.
6. Since seating capacity of classrooms and strength of students in every class both are variably ranging between 35 to 90, so allotment of rooms to classes needs extra care.

So manually generating a time table with these restrictions takes almost 2 weeks duration and really is a nightmare for us. As we have to generate time table after every six months so we waste too much time on generating timetable for our college.

We use Window 10 operating system. Can anybody suggest free (or reasonably priced) tool for generating timetable for our college? There are tools available but they are too costly.

Comment: I can write you a software that can do exactly what you need. For Mac or for Windows, also for mobile - iOS and if needed for Android too. How can we get in touch ?

Comment: Made a mockup for Mac OS. I can write a clone for each platform in about 1 day for each :-) Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Even better : why don't you ask some of your students to do it and give him credit for it or something ;-) It takes little time to do such a thing.

Comment: http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/features.html found this and https://www.emssoftware.com/what-we-do/classroom-scheduling and http://alternativeto.net/software/asc-timetables/

Comment: let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: just tested fet - it's awesome.

Comment: @daredevil.....I think FET you have suggested will work for me. Let me test it first.

Comment: any updates ? :D

Comment: I wonder how to install this package as there is no such .exe file in file fet-2.29.2, I think I need to install third party software first, but do not know which one.

Comment: http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/download.html with http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/download/fet-5.29.3.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [FET](http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/features.html) from a Romanian school. It's free, it has all the features you need. 
If you want something customized for your University, let me know.