# Multi-track event planning system

Tags: scheduling

I am looking to organise several training weekends. At each weekend there will be training sessions of varying lengths. Each session has at least one trainer and several attendees. Each trainer is able to train some or all of the available courses. There will be approx. six concurrent sessions across at least eight distinct venues/rooms, for approximately 100 attendees. In addition to this, it is a pre-requisite of the final weekend that attendees must have attended one of the first two weekends (though I see attendee management as a "nice to have").

Currently the timetable and attendance is managed using several large spreadsheets, but this becomes unwieldy when performing due diligence (ensuring the trainers allocated to each session are able to do so) and when creating timetables (producing both whole-event timetables, and individual trainer/attendee timetables) while ensuring there are no clashes!

The events are internal training within a charity (i.e. attendees do not pay) therefore there is minimal budget, but I would be willing to pay a small fee out of my own pocket for a good system in return for the reduced admin headaches!

I currently run Windows but can setup a *nix environment, and would strongly consider a hosted/online option. Systems I have found thus far appear to focus on room management (e.g. a shared room within an office - effectively a calendar) or academic conference management (initially promising as they can have multiple attendee tracks, but nothing really stood out as they seem to focus on manage the paper submission/review process).

Due to the lack of suitable systems turning up in search results I am at the point where I may write my own system, but would first like to reach out for recommendations first however!

Comment: http://www.pandarix.com/software-solutions/crm-software-for-events-venues.php

Comment: See this question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31707/college-university-time-table-generator?newsletter=1&nlcode=423026%7c1014   It discusses scheduling for a school, but it seems to me that the problems are virtually identical